# Почему происходит ошибка "undefined reference"?

Tags: c

При компиляции выдает происходит ошибка:

```
C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-7.2.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v5-
rev0/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.2.0/../../../../i686-
w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib32_libmingw32_a-
crt0_c.o):crt0_c.c:(.text.startup+0x39): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Вот мой код:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
printf("hello wordl");  
return 0;
}
```

Comment: А код, который производит такую ошибку, нам предлагается угадать самим?

Comment: @diraria Нет, там проблема совсем другая

Comment: а как вы компилируете?

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего - раз вы написали `main`, а компилятор ищет `WinMain` - вы задали в проекте создание не консольного приложения, а оконного, в котором вместо `main` используется `WinMain`.

Comment: Это бывает только в MSVC, а в MinGW нет такого разделения. И тот и другой вид проектов принимают и тот и другой вариант `main`.